# How to multiply two string fields in JasperReports?

Tags: xml-serialization, jasper-reports

How do I multiply two fields of type string (say, price and quantity) to obtain a result of type double? How to write this in an XML file?

I tried this in a variable expression, but it is not working:

```
new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{qpa}) * Double.parseDouble($F{price}))]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JasperReports will not automatically cast the variable expression to the variable class. @Vicky, your variable expression works for me once I changed the variable class from the default `java.lang.String` to `java.lang.Double`.

You should also check that the field classes of `qpa` and `price` are string, as that is what `parseDouble()` is expecting.

Also, if you are going to print the value of the variable in a textField, the expression class must also be changed to `java.lang.Double`.

(This only applies if you are writing your expressions in Java. If you change your report language from `java` to `groovy`, these casts will be performed automatically. I don't recommend this though.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this expression:

```java
Double.valueOf(Double.valueOf($F{qpa}).doubleValue()*Double.valueOf($F{price}).doubleValue())
```